# how can i stretch the y axis in ahistogram in r so that low values become more visible?

Tags: r, histogram, yaxis

I want to change the height of my bins of the lowest values. The thin line should be thicker. How can I do this? can i stretch the y axis with some code? so that there is the value 0.01 instead of 0.02 in the beginning?

Here is my code and a picture of the histogram.
thank you very much in advance!

```
#Industrie
x <-x <- hist(vec_Industrie, xlim= c(0,100), breaks = 30,ylim= c(0.00,0.1),freq=F, col="grey",main="CLC-Klasse: Industrie- und Gewerbeflächen", ylab="Relative Häufigkeiten", xlab="Temperaturen (°C)")  

m <- mean(vec_Industrie, na.rm=TRUE)

s <-  sd(vec_Industrie, na.rm=TRUE)

curve(dnorm(x,m,s),add=TRUE,lwd=1, col="blue", from = 7, to = 60) 
box()
```

[image]